# Rat is gasping and lying on the floor after being fed

Tags: health, rat

Spencer is my rat and he's about 5 months old, I fed him and his new buddy a few hours ago and I usually let them out to play for a few hours before bed. However, normally when I come in Spencer is usually running around the cage or crawling up it to be petted or for food. This time he was lying on the floor in a carpet square I have. His belly is sunken in and he was gasping and dribbling all over.

I am freaking out and I tried to grab him but he was hesitant and I gave him some fresh air which helped a little. I brought him to the bathroom and tried to help him but he did not want it so I snuggled him.

It has been about two hours since I noticed he has been acting this way. He also has a bite under his chin from his older friend (which I've now had separated for a while) and it was bleeding. I'm just really worried he won't be okay.

Comment: I suggest you take him to a vet. The only thing we can do here is giving you advice, but only a vet can examine and treat your pet.

Answer (score 8):

### You need to take him to the vet now.

There is no quick answers we can give you on the internet and by the sounds of it, the rat needs attention now. I would always be concerned about issues involving gasping or laboured breathing.

You need to act fast and unfortunately, this platform is not built to accommodate emergency support.

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t know any of that but much appreciated, He’s doing fine! I had switched him from little cotton pieces of bedding to clippings and he had eaten some and it was stuck around his teeth and all in his mouth so I had to rinse his mouth out and try and brush his teeth with a cotton swab. After I cleared it I left him be for a little bit in his own cage and he was fine and running around when I went to check! :)